Sharing PostgreSQL GraphQL API with PostGraphile Over the Internet
I'm using PostGraphile to rapidly develop GraphQL APIs. When I run the command npx postgraphile -c postgres://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/mydb --watch --enhance-graphiql --dynamic-json --cors in the CLI, the program provides me with an API to use on the front-end at http://localhost:5000/graphql. However, this URL is only accessible from my local machine. How can I share this URL over the internet so that other clients can access and use the API?
When trying to share the PostGraphile API URL (http://localhost:5000/graphql) over the internet, I expected other clients to be able to access and use the API. However, the URL is only accessible from my local machine, resulting in other clients being unable to access the API.

This is a networking question, not a programming question.  Maybe it should be addressed to superusers? Also, it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL, since the connection to PostgreSQL is the same regardless of where the connection to your web service comes from.

On which server at which domain, hosted by whom, do you want to run this (and your database)? Or do you still want to run it on your local computer but somehow make it available on the internet?

Have you read the deployment guides (e.g. https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/deploying-docker/, but there are specific ones for other platforms as well)?
